# Trying to retrieve events for multiple days c#

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve events for multiple days. Right now we have the day calculations as enums that get pushed here

```
  internal static class DayCalc
{
    public static DateTime GetDateTime(Enums.Day day = Enums.Day.Today)
    {
        DateTime retVal = DateTime.Now;

        if (day == Enums.Day.Tomorrow)
        {
            retVal = retVal.AddDays(1);
            retVal = SetTime(retVal);
        }
        else if (day == Enums.Day.DayAfterTomorrow)
        {
            retVal = retVal.AddDays(2);
            retVal = SetTime(retVal);
        }
        else if (day != Enums.Day.Today)
        {
            // -1, -2, -3 are handeled already so we can use enum Day as enum DayOfTheWeek now
            retVal = GetNextWeekday((DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), day.ToString()));
        }

        return retVal;
```

My problem is I would like to be able to get events for multiple day entries, Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the date/times returned you could add an extra method which calls your existing method:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateTimesOnly(IEnumerable<Enums.Day> days)
{
    foreach (var day in days)
        yield return GetDateTime(day);
}
```

If you need a reference to the Day enum you could use a dictionary (provided the input values are unique):

```
public static IDictionary<Enums.Day, DateTime> GetDaysAndDateTimes(IEnumerable<Enums.Day> days)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<Enums.Day, DateTime>();
    days.ToList().ForEach(d => result.Add(d, GetDateTime(d)));
    return result;
}
```

**Update:**

Since you already have an enum for a period, you could create an overload using periods:

```
public static DateTime GetDateTime(Enums.DateTimePeriod period = Enums.DateTimePeriod.Week)
{
    DateTime retVal = DateTime.Now;

    if (period == Enums.DateTimePeriod.Day)
    {
        retVal = retVal.AddDays(1);
        retVal = SetTime(retVal);
    }
    else if (period == Enums.DateTimePeriod.Week)
    {
        retVal = retVal.AddDays(7);
        retVal = SetTime(retVal);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: We have it set to give us calendar events based on which day is chose, and I would like to add in something that will return an entire week of events.

Comment: We have it posted on git if you wouldn't mind looking at it...and possibly letting me know if it's even possible.  https://github.com/Zunair/Google/tree/master/Google.Calendar

Comment: Since you already have a `DateTimePeriod` you could create an overload, i.e. `public static DateTime GetDateTime(Enums.DateTimePeriod period = Enums.DateTimePeriod.Week)` which could calculate the date time for a given period, the same way you do for days

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, I will put this in and see if I can get it to work. Thanks

Comment: well no luck on that, either im missing something or doing it wrong lol but when running it states specified value week was not found..